# How to decrypt TLS in WireShark if I can hook the application's crypto API calls?

Tags: tls, privacy, http, man-in-the-middle, wireshark

I hooked `BCryptEncrypt` and `BCryptDecrypt` calls of an executable. I can get the input arguments and output values of these functions. This program calls `BCryptEncrypt` to encrypt the data sent over TLS, and calls `BCryptDecrypt` to decrypt the data received from TLS. So the hook gave me a lot of unencrypted data over the TLS channel.

However, a single HTTPS request might split into several TLS packets, and thus during each call of the above functions, my hook can only get a portion of the whole HTTPS stream.

I'm wondering if there's a way to "decrypt" the TLS captures in WireShark, given that I have already got the plain text for all the encrypted data for the TLS packets. So that I can utilize the Follow HTTP Stream, Gzip uncompression and many other goodies in WireShark to help me analyze the capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to let Wireshark work directly on the application level data you've got. But you can create a new pcap based on these data and then use Wireshark to analyze this pcap. For example this can be done with a bit of Perl and the [Net::PcapWriter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::PcapWriter) module which lets you easily create a pcap and add TCP connections with your own application data to it:

```
use strict;
use Net::PcapWriter;
my $pcap = Net::PcapWriter->new('test.pcap');
my $conn = $pcap->tcp_conn('1.1.1.1',1234,'2.2.2.2',80);
$conn->write(0,"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:..."); # HTTP request from client
$conn->write(1,"HTTP/1.1 200 ok\r\n...");     # HTTP response from server
```

Similar things can probably done with Python and the famous [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library.